# How useful is it to buy an Apple TV to be used in India?

Tags: appletv

I live in India and love to use Apple products. Besides disabled Apple-TV features like Siri ([available only in 8 out of 80 launch countries](http://appleinsider.com/articles/15/09/09/siri-on-apple-tv-will-be-limited-to-just-8-of-80-launch-countries-apps-limited-to-200mb)), many streaming services are not available outside the US. Some devices are not so useful outside their intended ecosystems, is Apple TV one of them?